# rack-affiliates gem with localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rack

I'm messing with [Rack::Affiliates](https://github.com/alexlevin/rack-affiliates) but I don't know if it works with the domain localhost in development environment.

1º This is my config in `application.rb` file:

```
config.middleware.use Rack::Affiliates, {:param => 'aff_id', :ttl => 6.months, :domain => '.localhost'}
```

2º I send a email with a link and param `aff_id` something like:
`<%= link_to "accept invite", new_user_registration_url(:aff_id => @user.id) %>`

3º In root action:

```
  def index
    if request.env['affiliate.tag'] && affiliate = User.find_by_affiliate_tag(request.env['affiliate.tag'])
      logger.info "Halo, referral! You've been referred here by #{affiliate.name} from #{request.env['affiliate.from']} @ #{Time.at(env['affiliate.time'])}"
    else
      logger.info "We're glad you found us on your own!"
    end
   respond_to do |format|
     format.html
   end
 end
```

I'm getting the message on console:

```
We're glad you found us on your own!
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you remember to include `config.middleware.use Rack::Affiliates` in your config/application.rb file?

If not, add it and see what happens.

Otherwise you can try debugging by changing the `if` statement to:

```
if request.env['affiliate.tag']
  logger.info "request.env['affiliate.tag'] = #{request.env['affiliate.tag']}"
else
  logger.info "We're glad you found us on your own!"
end
```

This should tell you if the affiliate.tag is getting set and if so to what value.

Answer (score 0):

It's all due to `User.find_by_affiliate_tag`. have you any column named **affiliate_tag**. 
If your are inviting using this link `<%= link_to "accept invite", new_user_registration_url(:aff_id => @user.id) %>`  where you are using `@user.id` as **aff_id**.

So you have to use `User.find_by_id` instead of  `User.find_by_affiliate_tag`

Final code snippet of exmaple contoller will look like

```
class ExampleController < ApplicationController
  def index
    str = if request.env['affiliate.tag'] && affiliate = User.find_by_id(request.env['affiliate.tag'])
      "Halo, referral! You've been referred here by #{affiliate.name} from #{request.env['affiliate.from']} @ #{Time.at(env['affiliate.time'])}"
    else
      "We're glad you found us on your own!"
    end

    render :text => str
  end
end
```